# What type of exception is EEMessageException?

Tags: c#, windows

I tried googling but I can't find any documentation about what type of exception a EEMessageException is.

I observed it when running a C# application using a debugger with the options to stop on all exception on.

```
First-chance exception at 0x773cb9bc (KernelBase.dll) in....
Microsoft C++ exception: EEMessageException at memory location 0x0032b280
```

From the error message and given the stack trace is:

```
KernelBase.dll!_RaiseException@16()  + 0x58 bytes   
>   msvcr80.dll!__CxxThrowException@8()  + 0x46 bytes
```

I'm guessing its some sort of VC++ exception.

I'm aware that this is probably a handled exception and not causing any problems but I'm curious about what the EEMessageException is.

Comment: Seems to be something that is thrown in COM Interop.  Definitely a rather undocumented exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are seeing an unmanaged exception, it is thrown inside the CLR.  It is pretty generic, used to signal an error condition when it is buried deep in native code.  The "message" part of the name was intended for Microsoft testers.  Just wait for that exception to be turned into a managed one.  Or get swallowed if it is benign.

Or untick the Project > Properties > Debugging tab, "Enable unmanaged code debugging" checkbox so you won't see it.  Or use Debug > Windows > Exception Settings and untick the Thrown checkbox for Win32 exceptions so the debugger won't stop on these kind of exceptions.